Flow Data Table with View Only still hows "0 Items Selected" and also highlighting an item
This is very annoying.  I simply want to display a list of a few records in a flow.  I added a Data Table, I specified the "View only" option.  It displays the rows but it still says "0 Items selected" above the table.  Further, the user can click on an item to highlight it.  That's going to confuse the heck out of users.  They aren't going to know whether they have to select anything or not.  I know I've seen screenshots of tutorials that don't look like that.  Anyone know a way to fix this or is this just another annoying little thing in SF that doesn't really work the most useful way?

